# Add a speech bubble style arrow onto message bubble pointing to the sender of the message

Tags: botframework

I am hoping to add an arrow to the sent/received message bubble pointing at who sent the message.  This is included in the 'test in web chat' section through an SVG image (I noticed this through inspecting with the chrome console), and it would be great if Microsoft would include this option within the wider use of the chat bot.  It seems like a very mainstream way of styling chat apps, so I am surprised it is not included.

I have tried manually overwriting the CSS to achieve this, but have had no success.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue that has already been opened on the BotFramework-WebChat repo, issue [#1658](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1658), that addresses this want. Unfortunately, due to some complexities involving the underlying WebChat code, implementing this feature is not a possibility at this time.

I encourage you to comment on the issue indicating your interest. This will help give weight to the matter and (hopefully) spur development sooner than later.

Hope of help!

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you, I appreciate it.